# Grails ClassNotFoundException only in one subproject

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I'm pulling my hair over this crazy problem that doesn't make any sense to me. I have a large Grails 4 project with multiple sub-projects. In two of these subprojects, let's call them A and B, I have a dependency to a plugin (non-public plugin): `implementation group: 'dokumentlager', name: 'dokumentlager-grails4-plugin', version: "5.4.1"`.

This dependency has two transitive dependencies, as seen in the **External Libraries** list in IntelliJ:

[image]

In sub-project B a class from "dokumentlager-api" is used in a Service and imported like so:

```
import dokumentlager.api.Indholdstype
```

This gives no errors and I can start B normally.

However, in sub-project A I also import the same class and use in a Service, but there I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in dk.erst.plandata.integration.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class dk.erst.plandata.integration.faelleskomponenter.DokumentlagerPluginService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
    at dk.erst.plandata.integration.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class dk.erst.plandata.integration.faelleskomponenter.DokumentlagerPluginService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class dk.erst.plandata.integration.faelleskomponenter.DokumentlagerPluginService
    at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.isArtefact(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:129)
    at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:774)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.performGrailsInitializationSequence(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:112)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:94)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:231)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:78)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dokumentlager/api/Indholdstype
    at dk.erst.plandata.integration.faelleskomponenter.DokumentlagerPluginService.<clinit>(DokumentlagerPluginService.groovy:23)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:64)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:161)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.JobArtefactHandler.isArtefactClass(JobArtefactHandler.groovy:62)
    at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.isArtefact(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:125)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dokumentlager.api.Indholdstype
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

So far, I've tried:

1. Adding "dokumentlager-api" as an explicit dependency
2. Invalidated caches in IntelliJ
3. Manually deleted all caches in .gradle/
4. Re-cloned my repository
5. Reinstalled IntelliJ

How is it possible that with the same setup this gives me an error in project A but not in project B?! **I should add that we have another developer that CAN start A locally... so it seems to be a very local issue...**

PS: I'm using gradle 5.2

**EDIT**

I ran a build scan for my two sub-projects and they have the exact same dependencies in borth compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath:

[image]

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce that problem.  Can you share a small sample project which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure how though... that dependency is only available from our private repository :(

Comment: "that dependency is only available from our private repository" - I understood that it is a private repo.  It isn't clear why the example would have to reference that specific artifact.  I am sorry for the confusion and I am sorry that I can't help. Best of luck!